# Currency value with provided symbol in excel cell using C# Excel library

Tags: c#, excel, com-interop, excel-interop

I am creating excel file using c#. I am different columns settings like number , currency , date etc . I am setting range of excel cell and proving custom Number format. But when I am setting currency it is showing wrong symbol in excel file. Here is my code for column settings

```
int row = 9;
int index = 10;
int count = Report.Data.Count - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < columns.Count; i++) {
 switch (columns[i].Type.ToUpperInvariant()) {
  case ColumnSettingType.Number:
   {
    oRange = (Excel.Range) oSheet.Range[oSheet.Cells[index, i + 1], oSheet.Cells[index + count, i + 1]];
    oRange.NumberFormat = "#,###,###";
    break;
   }
  case ColumnSettingType.Currency:
   {
    oRange = (Excel.Range) oSheet.Range[oSheet.Cells[index, i + 1], oSheet.Cells[index + count, i + 1]];
    oRange.NumberFormat = "$ #,###,###.00";
    break;
   }
  case ColumnSettingType.Percentage:
   {
    oRange = (Excel.Range) oSheet.Range[oSheet.Cells[index, i + 1], oSheet.Cells[index + count, i + 1]];
    oRange.NumberFormat = "0.00%";
    break;
   }
  case ColumnSettingType.Date:
   {
    oRange = (Excel.Range) oSheet.Range[oSheet.Cells[index, i + 1], oSheet.Cells[index + count, i + 1]];
    oRange.NumberFormat = "$#,###,###.00";
    break;
   }
 }
 oSheet.Cells[row, i + 1] = columns[i].ColumnName;
}
```

My excel file is showing another symbol instead of **($)**, Also I need to show this symbol dynamically which I pass.

Need help.

[image]

Comment: look into the currency number format options in Excel `[$$-en-US]#,##0.00`

Comment: Why not showing dollar sign ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the NumberFormat property uses the $ symbol to indicate the cell is in Currency format - that uses the current locale currency symbol as far as I can see.

The actual currency symbol used for the cell/range can be set in the NumberFormatLocal property.

Setting both should display the value as "$ 1,016.89"

```
 var format = "$ #,##0.00";
 oRange.NumberFormat = format;
 oRange.NumberFormatLocal = format;
```